# NVL2 functionality as COALESCE function

Tags: sql, oracle

I m trying to achieve COALESCE functionality with NVL and NVL2. It seems to be working fine with NVL. However, NVL2 is not giving desired result. Am I missing out on something for NVL2.

**NVL**

```
WITH test_t
   (col_1, col_2, col_3) AS
(select 'a', null, null from dual
union
select null,'b',null from dual
union 
select null, null, 'c' from dual)
select nvl(nvl(col_1,col_2),col_3) from test_t;
```

Its giving desired output. Same thing I want to achieve with NVL2 its not giving desire result.

**NVL2**

```
WITH test_t
   (col_1, col_2, col_3) AS
(select 'a', null, null from dual
union
select null,'b',null from dual
union 
select null, null, 'c' from dual)
select nvl2(nvl2(col_1,col_1,col_2),col_2,col_3) from test_t;
```

NVL2 works in below fashion

```
NVL2( string1, value_if_not_null, value_if_null )
```

Need to understand if above requirement can be done with NVL2 or not? If yes then how?

Again this was interview question :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coalesce-like expression using NVL2 for 3 columns is

```
select nvl2(col_1,col_1,nvl2(col_2, col_2, col_3)) from test_t
```

Comment: Marked your answer as correct because with your way you could manage it with two NVL2 functions :)

Comment: It is correct, and also easy to read!

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
WITH test_t
   (col_1, col_2, col_3) AS
(select 'a', null, null from dual
union
select null,'b',null from dual
union 
select null, null, 'c' from dual)
select nvl2(nvl2(col_1,col_1,col_2),nvl2(col_1,col_1,col_2),col_3) from test_t;
```

I'm assuming the following holds true everytime:

nvl(val1, val2) = nvl2(val1, val1, val2)

Comment: Giving desired result hence upvoting

Answer (score 1):

There is a loggical error in `nvl2` approach givven above...

The correct way would be:

```
WITH test_t
   (col_1, col_2, col_3) AS
(select 'a', null, null from dual
union
select null,'b',null from dual
union 
select null, null, 'c' from dual)
select nvl2(nvl2(col_1,col_1,col_2),nvl2(col_1,col_1,col_2),col_3) from test_t
```

**result**:

```
a
b
c
```

Comment: Giving desired result hence upvoting